# Do really huge snakes spawn in the AI mode of Slither.io?

Tags: mobile, slither.io

Slither.io (for mobile) recently got an update with an AI mode, i.e. vs computer. I have been playing the game in AI mode for 10+ hours (yeah, got nothing else to do), but haven't seen a really big snake, like, 8-9k+. They appear on the rank list, but I never encountered one.

Is this a game flaw, or has anyone encountered one of those snakes?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the don't seem to appear on the map but they do appear on the list. This little trick is to make you think that you still have opponents to beat, making you to play longer*. There a no giant snakes in slither.io ai mode, so the best thing to do is to go to online mode and play with real players.

*This is from real experience:)